# can Java nio FileLock give the same guarantee as mlock system call?

Tags: java

can Java nio FileLock give the same guarantee as mlock system call? looking for something that can keep a memory region from being swapped out or swapped in (other words pinning like rdbms buffer pools normally do)

I see that mlock system call can lock a virtual page such that it won't be swapped out or in. so looking for something similar in plain Java but not through JNI/JNA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Java NIO's `FileLock` give the same guarantee as a `mlock` system call?

No.  `FileLock` implements "mutual exclusion" locking for a file or a region of a file.  It is something different.  (It is the analog of the `flock` syscall.  Compare `man 2 flock` with `man 2 mlock`.)

> I see that `mlock` system call can lock a virtual page such that it won't be swapped out or in.  I am looking for something similar in plain Java but not through JNI/JNA.

There is no way to do it in Java that doesn't involve calls to custom or 3rd-party native code.

The other thing to note is that the `mlock` system call requires either full "root" privilege or the CAP_IPC_LOCK privilege.

Finally, you typically don't have enough control over where Java objects are located in memory for page locking to be a sensible approach.  Any object in the heap is liable to be relocated by the GC without any notice.  The GC would not know anything the page locks ... so you would end up with the object no longer page locked, and other unrelated objects in the locked page.  So this would only be useful for off-heap memory nodes ... and you typically need to use JNI / JNA to create those.

Comment: Yes I want to do memory management off heap. So the only way to pin is to use jni..hmm I wish there was just like read write system calls are exposed in java

Comment: *I wish ...*.  Wishing doesn't help.  Submit a "request for enhancement" to the Java team.

Comment: Is there a way to do that? I thought it’s all internal to oracle..moreover I do think they will redirect to jni

Comment: Thanks. Will file one. Just looked at golang https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/ I believe java can have the same thing

Comment: However, if you want them to pay any attention, you will need to give a clear explanation of what you want, and a compelling case for why it would be worthwhile >>for the team<< to expend effort on this.  (My reaction to such an RFE would be "just use JNI" ...)

Comment: I agree. I bet they would redirect me to jni which is a pain to deal with but I guess I will give it a shot